# Hibernate 5: createNativeQuery() in Singleton pattern

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a DAO class which internally is querying the next_val from an Oracle sequence.

As this sequence is not bound to any entities, but simply querying the value for internal logic, I'm creating the native query every time the `getNextValueFromSequence()` method is invoked on the DAO as follows:

```
Query nextValQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE_VAL_SQL);
```

As I'm creating the query every time the method is invoked, I was thinking to refactor this to have the native query created in a singleton defined as a Spring bean, so that the query gets created only the first time my `getNextValueFromSequence()` it's invoked.

Is there any drawback in doing this? Would the Hibernate session give problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking advantage of named query feature provided by thet JPA specification:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "sequenceQuery", query = "<query>", resultClass = Integer.class)
```

The annotation has to be defined on some entity.

Then you get the query as follows:

```
Query nextValQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("sequenceQuery");
```

Thanks to that the query will be created only once during startup of the application.

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks for your answer. I was aware of this optoin, but unfortunately I can't use the `@NamedNativeQuery` as I don't have any entities bound to this sequence.

Comment: Thats not a problem. Specification does not enforce query to be relevant to the entity in which it is defined. So you can still have a go

Answer (score 0):

Query instance is bounded to the session, so it is not good idea to reuse the same Query instance.